# 'some' and 'many' functions from the 'Alternative' type class

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, some-and-many, alternative-functor

What are the functions `some` and `many` in the `Alternative` type class useful for? [Docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v:some) provide a recursive definition which I was unable to comprehend.

Comment: @Landei: I read the answer in that thread, and I still don't get it.

Comment: I just said this question is a duplicate, not that the original one had a good answer :-) Although it was good enough for me: I figured out that these functions are very likely not interesting for me...

Comment: @Landei: I am reaching about the same conclusion as you did. :-)

Comment: If you are going to close this question, please merge it with @Landei's. Don't delete it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`some` and `many` can be defined as:

```
some f = (:) <$> f <*> many f
many f = some f <|> pure []
```

Perhaps it helps to see how `some` would be written with monadic `do` syntax:

```
some f = do
  x <- f
  xs <- many f
  return (x:xs)
```

So `some f` runs `f` once, then "many" times, and conses the results. `many f` runs `f` "some" times, or "alternatively" just returns the empty list. The idea is that they both run `f` as often as possible until it "fails", collecting the results in a list. The difference is that `some f` immediately fails if `f` fails, while `many f` will still succeed and "return" the empty list in such a case. But what all this exactly *means* depends on how `<|>` is defined.

Is it only useful for parsing? Let's see what it does for the instances in base: `Maybe`, `[]` and `STM`.

First `Maybe`. `Nothing` means failure, so `some Nothing` fails as well and evaluates to `Nothing` while `many Nothing` succeeds and evaluates to `Just []`. Both `some (Just ())` and `many (Just ())` never return, because `Just ()` never fails! In a sense they evaluate to `Just (repeat ())`.

For lists, `[]` means failure, so `some []` evaluates to `[]` (no answers) while `many []` evaluates to `[[]]` (there's one answer and it is the empty list). Again `some [()]` and `many [()]` don't return. Expanding the instances, `some [()]` means `fmap (():) (many [()])` and `many [()]` means `some [()] ++ [[]]`, so you could say that `many [()]` is the same as `tails (repeat ())`.

For `STM`, failure means that the transaction has to be retried. So `some retry` will retry itself, while `many retry` will simply return the empty list. `some f` and `many f` will run `f` repeatedly until it retries. I'm not sure if this is useful thing, but I'm guessing it isn't.

So, for `Maybe`, `[]` and `STM` `many` and `some` don't seem to be that useful. It is only useful if the applicative has some kind of state that makes failure  *increasingly* likely when running the same thing over and over. For parsers this is the input which is shrinking with every successful match.

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say that `some (Just ())` evaluates to `Just (repeat ())` (even with the "in a sense" caveat), because that made me wonder if an expression like `some (Just ()) >>= return . head` might behave like `Just (repeat 1) >>= return . head`, but it doesn't; the latter terminates and the former doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

E.g. for [parsing](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) (see the "Applicative parsing by example" section).

Comment: I am not familiar with Parsec. I'd appreciate some explanation.

Comment: As far as I understand, if you have a parser `p` for X, then `some p` is a parser for 0 or more X and `many p` is a parser for 1 or more X.

Comment: @missingfaktor `some` and `many` are implementaed in terms of `<|>`. This combinator is useful also in other ways. Consider `Either`: `Just 0 <|> Just 1 = Just 0`, `Nothing <|> Just 2 = Just 2`, `Just 3 <|> Nothing = Just 3`, `Nothing <|> Nothing = Nothing`

Comment: @Ingo: I understood their use with respect to parsers, thanks. Still I am curious what these functions are useful for _in general_.

Comment: @FUZxxl: See my above comment.

Comment: @missingfaktor: that is the usual application; I'm not sure if `Alternative` is used for anything else.  You could say that "in general", `some` is used whenever you want something to run multiple times (but doesn't **have** to run), and `many` to run at least once.

Comment: @Ingo @ivanm Note that you have `some` and `many` backwards. `some` is one or more (i.e. `+` in regexps) and `many` is zero or more (i.e. `*`).

Comment: @Ingo just for the record, it's the other way around: `some` is one or more, `many` is 0 or more results collected from performing the same computation over and over. so for this to make sense some state passing (and alteration) must take place, reducing the domain of possibilities somehow, otherwise it will repeat ad infinitum. and state passing and parsing are closely related.