# Haskell - some, many implementation

Tags: haskell, some-and-many, alternative-functor

In the article: "[Write you a Haskell](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/WYAH.pdf)" (page 34) the following interpretation of "`some`" and "`many`" is given:

> Derived automatically from the `Alternative` typeclass definition are
>   the `many` and `some` functions. `many` takes a single function argument and
>   repeatedly applies it until the function *fails*, and then yields the
>   collected results up to that point. The `some` function behaves similar
>   except that it will fail itself if there is not *at least* *a single*
>   match.

```
-- | One or more.
some :: f a -> f [a]
some v = some_v
  where
    many_v = some_v <|> pure []
    some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v

-- | Zero or more.
many :: f a -> f [a]
many v = many_v
  where
    many_v = some_v <|> pure []
    some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v
```

I have been trying to understand this implementation for a while.

I dont understand how "`many`" and "`some`" could be applied to "lists" or "`Maybe`".

Also I am not sure about `(:) <$> v <*> many_v`.

How does one derive this?

Comment: I guess that's the Osmium of all Haskell books.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108608/what-are-alternatives-some-and-many-useful-for and its many links. (possible duplicate). [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681283/849891) a very good answer.

Comment: Have the linked entries answered our question or is there something still unclear?

Comment: It is clear, thank you

Comment: For `[]` and `Maybe` those two functions aren't really useful: but they are really useful for types like `StateT String []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `ghc/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs` there is this recursive declaration:

```hs
    ... :: f a -> f [a]
    ...
        many_v = some_v <|> pure []
        some_v = liftA2 (:) v many_v  -- (:) <$> v <*> many_v
```

The argument `v` must be a value of a type that is instance of
`Alternative` (and `Applicative` and `Functor`).
`v` is *lifted* already and just needs to be applied (`<*>`).
The application results in a lifted list.

`some` and `many` make recursive applications of the constructor of `v`,
and put the constructed values into a list.

- `some` stops application, when the first `empty` is constructed
- `many` continues application beyond that

`[]` is instance of `Alternative`:

```hs
instance Alternative [] where
    empty = []
    (<|>) = (++)
```

`some` tries with list:

```hs
  av = [[2], [2,3], [], [2,3,5]]
  some av                      -- no error, but never stops
  do {v <- some av; return v;} -- no error, but never stops
```

Comparing to `letter` in
[What are Alternative's "some" and "many" useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108608/what-are-alternatives-some-and-many-useful-for):

```hs
  import Control.Monad(Functor(..))
  import Control.Applicative
  import Data.Char
  newtype P a = P { runP :: String -> [(a,String)] }
  instance Functor P where
    fmap f (P q) = P (\s -> [ (f y,ys) | (y,ys) <- q s])
  instance Applicative P where
    pure x = P (\s -> [(x,s)])
    P p <*> P q = P (\s -> [(x y, ys) | (x,xs) <- p s, (y,ys) <- q xs])
  letter = P p where
    p (x:xs) | isAlpha x = [(x,xs)]
    p _ = []
  instance Alternative P where
    P p <|> P q = P (\s-> p s ++ q s)
    empty = P (\s-> [])
```

with usage:

```hs
  runP (many letter) "ab123"
```

`letter` is a smart constructor, that
constructs a value of `P` with field `runP` using local variable `p`.
(The result of the accessor) `runP` is a function.
`P` is a type implementing `Alternative` as well as a constructor.
`P` stands for parser.

`fmap` is not used in `some` and `many`.
`<*>` leads to an application of the function `runP`,
whose argument is not yet here.
Basically `some` and `many` construct a program that will eat from its argument.
The argument must be a list.
Due to laziness the recursion stops at the first constructor.

```hs
  p = some letter -- constructs a program accessed via @runP@
  runP p "a1" -- [("a","1")]
```

```hs
  q = some [2] -- basically also a program
  q -- never stops
```

Recursive application is not `empty` (`[]` for list),
because there is no source of criteria to stop, i.e. no input.

These stop:

```hs
  some [] -- []
  many [] -- [[]]
  some Nothing -- Nothing
  many Nothing -- Just []
```

There are more requirements on the argument of `some` and `many` (`v`).

- `v` is value of a type that is instance of `Alternative`.
- The recursive application of the constructor of the `v` type must stop with `empty`.
- `v` must contain a function applied during construction with `<*>` to have stop criteria.

Conclusion:
`some` and `many` cannot be applied to list values,
even though list implements `Alternative`.

Why does list implement `Alternative`?
I think, it is to add the `Monoid` interface `<|>` and `empty` on top of `Applicative`,
not because of `some` and `many`.

```hs
  foldr (<|>) [] [[2],[],[3,4]] -- [2,3,4]
```

`some` and `many` seem to be just for parser construction
or more generally construction of a program consuming input
and producing more outputs, of which some can be `empty`.
That is quite general already.
But the place in `Alternative` is only justified,
if most of `Alternative` instances have a sensible usage for it.
That is not the case.

Comment: btw `some [2] = x where { x = (:) <$> [2] <*> (x <|> pure []) = [ (2:) ] <*> (x <|> pure []) = fmap (2:) (x <|> pure []) = fmap (2:) x <|> pure [2] = map (2:) x ++ [[2]] }`