# What do the "some" and "many" functions of Alternative do?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, some-and-many, alternative-functor

I'm working through Write You a Haskell, and I'm on the part where he implements "Nanoparsec", a Haskell parser from first principles. I'm getting stuck on the `Alternative` instance of the parser, specifically the `some` and `many` implementations:

```
instance Alternative Parser where
  -- empty = ...
  -- (<|>) p q = ...
  some v = some_v
    where
      many_v = some_v <|> pure []
      some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v
  many v = many_v
    where
      many_v = some_v <|> pure []
      some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v
```

I have no idea what these two functions are doing. From what I can see, `some` takes a parser, applies it, and concatenates the result until the input is used up. But `many` looks like it does the same thing. What's happening here?

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: if a regex/parser is your applicative, some is `+` (one or more) and many is `*` (zero or more)

Comment: Additionally, [here is a very nice explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681283/2751851) in an answer to another duplicate.